# Cannot import script functions from another script

Tags: python, python-import

I've the following hierarchy:

```
.root
  /program/main.py
  /functions/myfunctions.py
```

And using my main.py I want to use the functions present in myfunctions.py script. For that I've defined my **PYTHONPATH** AS ./root/functions and I have this as the import on my script:

```
from functions import myfunctions as func
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a problem with the working directory. This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/16672014) gives some answers on how to solve that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your `PYTHONPATH` as `./root/functions`, so everything(modules/packages) *"inside"* that directory is recognizable by Python. `./root/functions` directory is gonna get inserted to the `sys.path`. These paths are where Python loader checks to find modules and packages.

Just import the `myfunctions.py`:

```py
import myfunctions as func
```

If you had defined `PYTHONPATH` as `./root`, then you would have access to `functions` directory. (It became your [namespace package](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/) for more information)

Answer (score -1):

Import builtin module pathlib
Add the following code in your myfunctions.py

```
from pathlib import Path
Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```